# how to set static ip to pc

Tags: ip, dhcp, static-ip-address

I use tor proxy and i set the tunnel port to `192.168.1.2:9050`.

I also set my router dhcp that give `192.168.1.2` to my pc

but my problem is that sometimes I use another router or my phone hotspot and they give my pc anothre ip (like `192.168.43.164/24`) . I can't set their dhcp. so tor doesn't work.

Is there any way to always get the same ip ?

Or Is there any way to refer my wifi ip (something like localhost that refer to `127.0.0.1`) to set in tor?

Comment: You can ask this question in Ask Ubuntu community.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone hotspot gives you a different DHCP's IP because it is threated as another network bridging one network (your PC) to another one (current network connected on your phone).

If you are using wireless hotspot and connecting to your phone's network on wi-fi, that is not possible because tethering IP that is provided for your phone router to use DHCP services is hardcoded in com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering, unless you have root access privileges.
And that it the reason to your phone routing service (USB Bridged or Wi-Fi Hostpot) gives you always an `192.168.42.X` IP address.

If you are using Android, you can get more details in this thread on Android Enthusiasts in Stack Exchange:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499/how-configure-the-dhcp-settings-of-wifi-tethering-hotspot-on-android